# Объединение стилей компонентов и css

Tags: css, reactjs, nextjs, material-ui, styled-components

Решил сделать небольшой блог (справочник) на nextjs и взял к нему Material-UI.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Из базы подгружается обычный HTML контент на который не распространяются стили (h*, p, li и т.п ) т.к. по правилам Material-UI все должно оборачиваться в *Typography*.

Какие есть способы решения, кто и как решал такие вопросы?
Если делать свой css, выглядит дико и поддерживать сложно.
Парсить html тоже как-то выглядит странно...

Comment: "выглядит дико" - не, дико это `<Typography variant="h1" component="h2">`. "Из базы подгружается обычный HTML" - тоже выглядит странно. "по правилам Material-UI все должно оборачиваться в Typography" - сомнительное утверждение. IMHO

Comment: но если "так нужно" 1) изучаем первоисточник https://material.io/develop/web/docs/typography (Basic Usage) 2) смотрим что получаем на выходе `Material-UI` 3) сравниваем 4) ваяем реакт компонент обёртку `class="mdc-typography"`(или что там у  `Material-UI` ) устанавливаем для его потомков "(h*, p, li и т.п )" стили, один из вариантов стилей ...